# SQL SELECT statement inside WHERE IN ()

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, where-in

I am trying to make a Select onto a huge List with another Select as filter. I was trying following query:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @ids
SELECT TOP 1 ...
-- returns D2820EDA-5F00-4EE8-A4E0-992E74D25C09
-- 0 seconds execution

SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM @ids)
```

**My problem is that this query takes way too long (more than a minute), which is currently not acceptable.**

The same Select query with a fixed value takes about 3 seconds.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list
WHERE id IN ('D2820EDA-5F00-4EE8-A4E0-992E74D25C09')
```

I got the same execution time for 100+ filter values.

What can I do to filter my values with same speed as I would set fixed string values inside the IN statement?

EDIT: the 'id' column inside 'list' is not unique and has more than one result.

EDIT2: I've tried it with a JOIN statement. (execution time even longer than 2 minutes):

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list AS ud
JOIN @ids AS ids
ON ud.id= ids.id
```

and with a string result (execution time 1+ minute):

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @result = STUFF(
(SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), filterId) + ',' FROM Filters
WHERE ...
FOR xml path('')) + 'empty'
,1,1,'');

SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list AS ud
WHERE ',' + @result LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), ud.id) + ',%'
```

Comment: Use `exists`. Your query is incomplete in your question so I cannot offer anything further.

Comment: 3 seconds for a single value is also a lot. Does that `id` column of "list" have an index?

Comment: I've tried it with exists, same result... the list has about 4,5 M entries so 3 seconds is acceptable.

Comment: As @ids .id is a PRIMARY KEY you can try join as well.

Comment: @Serg this solutions is slow as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do. ie:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @ids (id) values (...);
```

and then query:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list
WHERE id IN (Select id from @ids);
```

or:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
   FROM list
   WHERE exists (select * from @ids i where i.id = list.id);
```

or:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3
   FROM list t1
   inner join @ids i on i.id = t1.id;
```

and all of them would be fast. Taking it too long for you should be related to something else. You have an index on id already, I assume.

Likely your cached query plan is bad. You could try with adding option (Recompile). ie:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM list
WHERE id IN (Select id from @ids)
Option (Recompile);
```

And if your in values are a lot (thousands of Guids to pass) then I suggest using a CLR based parser TVF that gets them as a comma separated value and parses to a table on server side.

EDIT: I don't know what made me think this was SQL server. Maybe I saw another question's tag. Anyway, I will keep this. Now I see why I thought SQL server, because of syntax in your samples. It is very likely SQL server even though you didn't tag your backend.

EDIT: I just tested this with 10 keys on a 5 million parts table (partId, partNumber, QtyAvailable, Price):

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
INSERT INTO @ids(id)
VALUES('D5DCE10E-513C-449D-8E34-8FE771FA464A')
    , ('EAC65501-21F5-F831-FB07-DCFEAD50D1D9')
    , ('30F20823-885A-332F-86EF-B08B142F744C')
    , ('49849363-2487-4351-0761-57F581B71E46')
    , ('32502023-4B75-D650-7525-3868B79E7C31')
    , ('D69804D7-534E-3C43-DBAE-9F37E5E516D6')
    , ('8413D734-24E4-53AA-38FF-7BA6B8CF19BA')
    , ('55036E2E-A022-67B9-307A-8A53AB77D5CF')
    , ('0EC2F7C3-43B6-7002-4B85-A95549D2382F')
    , ('2E017358-1FE7-316B-A1ED-38ED11E6AD18');

SELECT * FROM dbo.parts AS p WHERE p.partID IN( SELECT id FROM @ids);
```

Took 18 milliseconds.

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.parts AS p
WHERE  p.partID IN ( 'C727963F-C1B5-FE0C-1141-6B919346DF69'
                   , 'CDBAB6F8-AB42-0DDE-51CD-AEAECAE914D7'
                   , 'D162D88D-ABA9-FCE8-F651-B45601340B46'
                   , '26AD28EF-846B-C4FF-281C-06F4AA958157'
                   , '5000857A-8A0D-F500-E2C3-087443B5C60D'
                   , '59C386F4-0412-347B-3F03-D7AB0428572D'
                   , '0524D4A8-34A4-EA75-392A-1716DBF8A6A1'
                   , 'F350E8A4-2F42-E21D-C308-04912065EFF8'
                   , 'AA31FB13-FF0C-4986-9E1E-1F081028806F'
                   , '4890072E-0B3B-E5FF-B788-FA2E2E6668AC'
                   );
```

Took 11 milliseconds.

I think difference is not significant and might be different in repeated tests. Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE).

Comment: Yes, it is an SQL Server, sorry... My biggest concern is why it fetches many times faster with fixed GUID string values than with a fetched table of GUID's.

Comment: @Senad, it is fast with fixed or not. With fixed might be slightly faster because of generated execution plan. Did you try with recompile - I just tested now and adding my results.